# how to update the polars dataframe

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I want to update a polars library dataframe,

polars syntax/command which I used for the purpose:
df[0, 'A'] = 'some value'

but the above code gives an error:
**ValueError: cannot set with list/tuple as value; use a scalar value**
I am using polars 0.13.55

The above coode was previously working in polars 0.13.51

**Minimal Code to reproduce the problem:**

```
df = pl.DataFrame( { "IP": ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2'], "ISP" :   
                    ["N/A", "N/A"] } )

isp_names = { '1.1.1.1' : 'ABC', '2.2.2.2' : 'XYZ' }

i = 0
for row in df.rows():
    for ip, isp in isp_names.items():
        if(row[0] == ip):
            df[i, 'ISP'] = isp #**This line gives the Value error**
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Have you got a minimal working example to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Can you do: ```df.columns```?

Comment: yes, I can do df.columns

Comment: I updated the question with the minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you might be trying to update the values of DataFrame, particularly where values are missing (the "N/A" values).

In addition the advice of @jvz, I would recommend using a left [`join`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html) for your purposes, rather than using a dictionary and a for loop.  Using for loops is **very** slow, and is to be avoided.  By contrast, a left `join` will be very performant, and is built for exactly these types of situations.

We'll take this in steps.

First, let's first expand your example.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"IP": ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3", "4.4.4.4"],
     "ISP": ["N/A", "N/A", "PQR", "N/A"]}
)
df
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────┬─────┐
│ IP      ┆ ISP │
│ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ str │
╞═════════╪═════╡
│ 1.1.1.1 ┆ N/A │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2.2.2 ┆ N/A │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.3.3.3 ┆ PQR │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.4.4.4 ┆ N/A │
└─────────┴─────┘
```

Notice that we have three rows with "N/A" values, but one row that already has a valid value, "PQR".

Next, let's convert your dictionary of updated ISP values to a DataFrame, so that we can join the two DataFrames.

```py
isp_df = pl.DataFrame(
    data=[[key, value] for key, value in isp_names.items()],
    columns=["IP", "ISP_updated"],
    orient="row",
)
isp_df
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────┬─────────────┐
│ IP      ┆ ISP_updated │
│ ---     ┆ ---         │
│ str     ┆ str         │
╞═════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1.1.1.1 ┆ ABC         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2.2.2 ┆ XYZ         │
└─────────┴─────────────┘
```

Now, we simply `join` the two DataFrames.  The `how="left"` ensures that we keep all rows from `df`, even if there are no corresponding rows in `isp_df`.

```py
df.join(isp_df, on="IP", how="left")
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────────────┐
│ IP      ┆ ISP ┆ ISP_updated │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ ---         │
│ str     ┆ str ┆ str         │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════════════╡
│ 1.1.1.1 ┆ N/A ┆ ABC         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2.2.2 ┆ N/A ┆ XYZ         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.3.3.3 ┆ PQR ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.4.4.4 ┆ N/A ┆ null        │
└─────────┴─────┴─────────────┘
```

Notice the `null` values in `ISP_updated`.  These are cases where you had no updated values for a particular `IP` value.

To complete the process, we use `fill_null` to copy the values from the `ISP` column into the `ISP_updated` column for those cases where `isp_df` had no updates for a particular `IP` value.

```py
(
    df
    .join(isp_df, on="IP", how="left")
    .with_column(
        pl.col("ISP_updated").fill_null(pl.col("ISP"))
    )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────────────┐
│ IP      ┆ ISP ┆ ISP_updated │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ ---         │
│ str     ┆ str ┆ str         │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════════════╡
│ 1.1.1.1 ┆ N/A ┆ ABC         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2.2.2 ┆ N/A ┆ XYZ         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.3.3.3 ┆ PQR ┆ PQR         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.4.4.4 ┆ N/A ┆ N/A         │
└─────────┴─────┴─────────────┘
```

Now, your `ISP_updated` column has the updated values for each ISP.  If you want, you can drop and rename columns so that your final column is labeled `ISP`.

```py
(
    df
    .join(isp_df, on="IP", how="left")
    .with_column(
        pl.col("ISP_updated").fill_null(pl.col("ISP"))
    )
    .drop("ISP")
    .rename({"ISP_updated": "ISP"})
)
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────┬─────┐
│ IP      ┆ ISP │
│ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ str │
╞═════════╪═════╡
│ 1.1.1.1 ┆ ABC │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2.2.2 ┆ XYZ │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.3.3.3 ┆ PQR │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.4.4.4 ┆ N/A │
└─────────┴─────┘
```

As the size of your DataFrames gets large, you will definitely want to avoid using for loops.  Using `join` will be **far** faster.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the error on the latest version (0.13.56), so updating polars may help.

May I also suggest two improvements to the code, where the second improvements avoids the issue you run into altogether?

First, a more Pythonic version:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame( {"IP": ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2'], 
                    "ISP": ["N/A", "N/A"] } )
isp_names = { '1.1.1.1' : 'ABC', '2.2.2.2' : 'XYZ' }

for i, row in enumerate(df.rows()):
    df[i, 'ISP'] = isp_names[row[0]]
```

I.e., use `enumerate` to keep your `i` aligned with `row`, and do not loop `isp_names` separately but simply get the value by the key.

Second, Polars has an excellent [expression system](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/intro.html), meaning you do not have to pre-allocate `ISP` column or write a loop:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame( { "IP": ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']})
isp_names = { '1.1.1.1' : 'ABC', '2.2.2.2' : 'XYZ' }
df.with_column(pl.col("IP").apply(isp_names.get).alias("ISP"))
```

which returns `df` as:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────┬─────┐
│ IP      ┆ ISP │
│ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ str │
╞═════════╪═════╡
│ 1.1.1.1 ┆ ABC │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2.2.2 ┆ XYZ │
└─────────┴─────┘
```